# Graceful Shutdown of HDFS with Docker

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs

I am playing around with Docker and a simple HDFS cluster.  Currently a single node cluster.

The following script is used to start the cluster.

[SequenceIQ Docker Image](https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/blob/master/bootstrap.sh)

When reading more about docker it seems that for shutdown it calls a SIGQUIT on process id 1.  How badly does this affect the hdfs file system? Not sure if the SIGQUIT would be propogated to the child process.

```
root          1      0  0 08:49 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
root         23      1  0 08:49 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root        138      1  9 08:49 ?        00:00:04 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_namenode -Xmx1000m -   Djava.net.preferIPv4Sta
root        269      1  9 08:49 ?        00:00:04 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_datanode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Sta
root        451      1  8 08:49 ?        00:00:03 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_secondarynamenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.pref
root        636      1 14 08:49 ?        00:00:04 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_resourcemanager -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=
root        742      1 12 08:49 ?        00:00:04 /usr/java/default/bin/java -Dproc_nodemanager -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/usr
```